# get value inside a input date

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a input Text date type and i'm trying to get value when input text is fill or some value clicked inside,  what event i need to catch value inside the input?

I put a keyup from jquery but only work it when someone press a key, but in this field  date type you can click it in the arrows and my values ​​do not update and this value neither update when i get value from database.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input#name").on("keyup",function(){
    var valor=  $(this).val();
     var date=age(value) 
      $("div#messaje p").html(date);
  })    ;
});
</script>


<body>
Enter your name: <input id="name" type="date">
<div id="messaje"><p>value update from input text date type</p></div>
</body>
```

I hope to get the value of my input no matter how the data reaches him

Comment: It's not recommended to use use `name` as an id. Because name is an html attribute. [more info](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm)

Comment: Thanks! i appreciate it alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I think your first problem is that you using the wrong event you should use change
this is your input

```
<input type="date" id="start">
```

then you should write your event handler like this

```
object = document.getElementById("start");
object.addEventListener("change", function(){
 alert (document.getElementById("start").value)

});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. A key-up event wont be triggered on the datePicker because you don't use a keyboard to interact with it. Listen for the change event instead.
2. Always keep your javascript above where your body tag ends.
3. I don't know what you tried to do in `var date=age(value)`, for time being I've omitted it.

Attached working snippet.

Thanks, A.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
Enter your name: <input id="name" type="date">
<div id="messaje"><p>value update from input text date type</p></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#name").on("change",function(){
    var valor = $(this).val();
    $("#messaje p").html(valor);
  });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the event  `keyup` to `change`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dateInput").on("keyup change", function() {
    var valueDate = $(this).val();
    console.log(valueDate);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
I'm using a input Text date type and i'm trying to get value when input text is fill or some value clicked inside, what event i need to catch value inside the input? I put a keyup from jquery but only work it when someone press a key, but in this field
date type you can click it in the arrows and my values ​​do not update and this value neither update when i get value from database.




<body>
  Enter your name: <input id="dateInput" type="date">
  <div id="messaje">
    <p>value update from input text date type</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: this work only when i press the arrows but if value comes from to a database don't work, but it is an advance, thanks!

Comment: so try `keyup change`, this will do the job, welcome